# creating a read-only user on Google Cloud Platform (GCP), PostgreSQL - possible?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

Seemingly a simple task - creating a read-only user on PostgreSQL. However, PostgreSQL is on Google CLoud Platform (GCP), where the things don't seem to work as expected.

So, I'm trying to do these:

```
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE "my-db" FROM "ro-user";
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "my-db" TO "ro-user";
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "ro-user";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO "ro-user";
```

However, getting permission denied:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "ro-user";
ERROR:  permission denied for table SequelizeMeta
```

Is it even possible to create a read-ony user with PostgreSQL on Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: Yes it is possible, I'm able to create a read only access user in Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL. Can you try to connect/login first as postgres in your database before to execute again the command `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "ro-user";`

Comment: Are you using Postgres in [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) or [Cloud SQL for PostreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/introduction)?